# Deconstruct DNAstringsSets into normal strings

Tags: r, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

This comes from an R library called  ["VariantAnnotation"](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/VariantAnnotation.html) and its dependency ["Biostrings"](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html)

I have a DNAstringsSetList and I want to transform it into a normal list or a vector of strings.

```
library(VariantAnnotation)

fl <- system.file("extdata", "chr22.vcf.gz", package="VariantAnnotation")

vcf <- readVcf(fl, "hg19")

tempo <- rowRanges(vcf)$ALT  # Here is the DNAstringsSetList I mean.

print(tempo)

A DNAStringSet instance of length 10376
    width seq
[1]     1 G
[2]     1 T
[3]     1 A
[4]     1 T
[5]     1 T
...   ... ...
[10372]     1 G
[10373]     1 G
[10374]     1 G
[10375]     1 A
[10376]     1 C

tempo[[1]]
A DNAStringSet instance of length 1
width seq
[1]     1 G
```

But I don't want this format. I just want strings of the bases, in order to insert them as a column in a new dataframe. I want this:

```
G
T
A
T
T
```

I have accomplished this with this package method:

```
as.character(tempo@unlistData)
```

However, it returns 10 rows more than tempo has! The head and tail of this result and of tempo are exactly the same, so somewhere in the middle there are 10 extra rows that should not have been formed (not NAs)

Comment: a reproducible example would be helpful here!

Comment: So what is your question? We surely need to see data that reproduces the error in order to help you with the length issue, If that is your question

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question to make it clearer and perhaps reproducible. My question is: how do I transform a DNAstringsSetList into a normal list or a vector of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `as.character` on either a `DNAString` or a `DNAStringSet`.

```
as.character(tempo[1 : 5])
# [1] "G" "T" "A" "T" "T"
```

Comment: I've tried that several times: and get error: " Error in as.vector(x, mode = "character") : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector"

It works for you?

Comment: @RicardoGuerreiro It definitely works. Make sure the {Biostrings} package is actually loaded. If the problem persists, restart your R session. If it *still* persists, reinstall the {Biostrings} package.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop solves the issue, using the toString function of the same library:

```
ALT <-0
for (i in 1:nrow(vcf)){ ALT[i] <- toString(tempo[[i]]) }
```

However, I have no idea why tempo@unlistData retrieves too many rows. It is not trustworthy.